# Agente da passiva ou complemento nominal?

Tags: verbos, adjetivos, voz-passiva

Na frase "Vivia cercado de amigos sinceros", por que "de amigos sinceros" é agente da passiva (segundo o gabarito de um concurso) e não complemento nominal? No meu entender, "cercado" aqui é adjetivo e não verbo, uma vez que "vivia", neste caso, é verbo de ligação, significando "estar sempre", e todos os particípios passados são adjetivos quando vêm em frases predicativas.

Answer (score 2):

#### Definições

*Agente da Passiva:* Aquele que faz a ação na voz passiva

*Complemento Nominal:* Complementa um nome (Substantivo, Adjetivo ou Advérbio)

---

#### Exemplo de agente passiva

Para encontrar o termo, é necessário verificar quem faz a ação (*quem cerca?*). Caso tenha dúvida, a dica é você passar para a voz ativa, por exemplo:

**Voz Passiva:**

> *[Eu]* Vivia cercado **de amigos sinceros**

**Voz Ativa:**

> **Amigos sinceros** *me* cercavam

Nesse contexto, *"de amigos sinceros"* faz a ação de cercar, por isso é considerado *agente da passiva*.

*Obs.:* Os termos *"Vivia cercado"* são uma locução verbal.

---

#### Exemplo de complemento nominal

Observemos a seguinte frase: *A mulher está apaixonada pelo cunhado.* Agora basta perguntar quem faz a ação (*quem se apaixonou?*).

Na frase supramencionada, quem faz a ação é o sujeito (*A mulher*), por conseguinte podemos descartar a alternativa que diz que é *agente da passiva*.

**Análise da oração**

```
 A mulher  está apaixonada  pelo cunhado.
└────┬───┘└───────┬───────┘└──────┬──────┘
     │            │               └──────── Complemento Nominal de *apaixonada*
     │            └──────────────────────── Locução Verbal
     └───────────────────────────────────── Sujeito e também o termo que faz a ação de se apaixonar
```

Comment: Entendo, mas como saber quando um verbo no particípio passado é um adjetivo? Eu tinha lido neste link (https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/adjetivo-vs-participio-passado/34525) que, sempre que ele viesse depois de um verbo de ligação, como é o caso da frase em questão, seria adjetivo. Ora, sendo um adjetivo, não faz sentido classificar a expressão que vem depois como complemento nominal. Com que regra gramatical eu não estou atinando aqui? Obrigado.

Comment: @Sasaki Desconheço a regra citada. Aliás, *sempre* na língua portuguesa é um problema (por isso é raro), os termos dependem do contexto. Uma das dicas para descobrir se o é um verbo, é transpor a frase para voz ativa. No [**link**](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/adjectivo-vs-participio-passado/24270) há uma dica no item 2.